# Why does plucking nose hair cause tears in the eyes?

Tags: human-biology

It's not a particularly sad or painful thing to pluck a few nose hairs, but it's common for the tear ducts to wet up when doing this.

I would like to know the physiological reason for the correlation, how/why are the tear ducts and nose hairs related in the human body?

Comment: unreferenced, but here you go: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061231043153AAaJdCT

Comment: Is this for real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure, here's a working theory. The tear collection ducts feed into the nose. That's why when you cry you have a runny nose. When you pluck nose hairs you irritate the nasal mucosa, so that causes a reflex which attempts to flush out whatever might be causing a problem.

Comment: It might be an overstimulation of the sneeze reflex neural circuit, which causes tearing instead of sneezing. I do get a feeling similar to the "I'm about to sneeze" along with lacrimation.

Answer (score 4):

Also, tears are an intrinsic pain response and considering the dermal-derivative nature of hair, there are loose nerve endings ensnaring the follicular area, so the sensory neurons detect pain and tears are a physical manifestation of the pain, cuing the body to avoid that stimulus again.

Comment: +1. Innervation of the nose is extremely sensitive.  It's primarily a combination of this and what Armatus said above, plus the fact that AndroidPenguin mentioned of the connection between the nose and tear ducts.